# How to add automatically a color for a query made in Access

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, color, personal-geodatabase

I made an Access database with my polygons and my Exceltable with data about floods. I linked the specific row to my shapefile table and made a query table of it.

With the manual way I gave the shapefile with "Convert symbology to Representation" automatically the color red (red is linked to a colorstyle based on the amount 18 floods). With this function the shapefile will be opened with the right (red) color and not with for example blue.

I would like to add a function like this to the query shapefile. The attribute table of this shapefile automatically changes when I add a flood to it in Access, but this shapefile still opens with the blue color instead of the red one (the Convert symbology to representation tool doesn't work for the query). When I already changed the color to red and add a new flood, the colorstyle also stay at 18, but the total amount (where the color is based on) is already 19.

I there a way to solve this problem?